# How can I keep IE10 current, but not upgrade to IE11?

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-10, auto-update, internet-explorer-11

I have a Window 7 VM with Internet Explorer 10 that I use for browser testing which I don't want auto-updated to Internet Explorer 11.  I have installed the [IE11 Automatic Update Blocker Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40722) and ran the `ie11_blocker.cmd /B`command, so I know that IE11 won't be installed.

However, I still would like to get any IE10 updated, including security fixes.  As of today (18 Jan 2014), I have the versions below and `Install new versions automatically` unchecked

> Version: 10.0.9200.16750
>
> Update Versions: 10.0.12 ([KB2898785](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2898785/en-us))

**Question:**  How can I find the most current version of IE10 available and is this the best way to keep this VM at IE10?

Comment: Is not the update to ie10, ie11.

Comment: This question belongs to [Super User](http://superuser.com/) rather than SO.

Comment: In deciding whether this belongs here or Super User, I thought it fell under the "software tools commonly used by programmers" topic (as my particular need is JavaScript and web standards support).